# NGINX random 403 errors on page and static images

Tags: nginx

I have a problem with getting random 403 errors with NGINX.
On a page "profile/user.name.1" I have static images, but they are not loading.
I get the following message:

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)".
```

When I try to reach another page explicitly from this page, I get a "403 Forbidden" message.
I run nginx with user "nginx", I tried running it with "myuser nginx",
from http://nicholasorr.com/blog/2008/07/22/nginx-engine-x-what-a-pain-in-the-bum/

The permissions on this image folder are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser nginx   4096  5 jun 20:54 pics
```

The permissions on my index.php file is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myuser nginx  2517 11 jun 23:34 index.php
```

Edit:
When I check the permissions on the whole path, with:

```
namei -mo /usr/share/nginx/html/myuser/public/img/pics
```

I got:

```
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  usr
drwxr-xr-x root  root  share
drwxr-xr-x root  root  nginx
drwxr-xr-x root  root  html
drwxr-xr-x myuser nginx myuser
drwxr-xr-x myuser nginx public
drwxr-xr-x myuser nginx img
drwxr-xr-x myuser nginx pics
```

How can I fix the random 403 errors?

Comment: Don't forget to check the permissions of the whole path leading up to the `pics`  directory with for instance  `namei -mo /absolute/path/to/pics/`.

Comment: Could you try `chmod o+rx /usr/share/nginx/html/myuser/public/img/pics` just to be sure?

Comment: I tried what you sayd Kęstutis, doesn't work. When I refresh the "profile/user.name.1" the css doesn't load either, so it maybe is a static file problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, weird it was misconfiguration in my NGINX default.conf. I used config that I found on the internet, I just commented these two:

```
location ~ /\. { 
    deny all; access_log off; 
    log_not_found off;
}

if ($http_referer ~* (jewelry|viagra|...|babes)) {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: which of those blacklisted words match the domain of the request =)?